# How to get first week number of the month - javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am populating all the months in Dropdown list, and i am enabling up to current month and remain months will be disabled, like

```
var date = new Date();   

var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

var weeknum=//getting week number of the month

var options = $('#ddlMonth option');

var values = $.map(options, function (option) {
    return option.value;
});

for (var i = 0; i <= values.length; i++) {
    if (i > month) {
        $("#ddlMonth option[value=" + i + "]").attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
$('#ddlMonth').val(month);
```

Now I want to disable month if current week of the current month is first week.

Comment: Are you using [ISO 8601 standard week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) or some local week numbering system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date.prototype.getMonthWeek = function(){
    var firstDay = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 1).getDay();
    return Math.ceil((this.getDate() + firstDay)/7);
}
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ay10bmpm/

Ref

http://www.somethinghitme.com/2010/04/14/how-to-get-the-week-in-a-month-for-a-date-with-javascript/

Comment: @sanjay Notice, that this snippet doesn't give ISO week.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(0,0,0);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+4-(d.getDay()||7));
    return Math.ceil((((d-new Date(d.getFullYear(),0,1))/8.64e7)+1)/7);
};
```

This will get you the week in year and from this is simple math. (maybe not so simple for 5 weeks per month).

Or you can get the number of the week function from this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/OlsonDev/5mXF6/1/ (works with 5 weeks, tested)